# Maxima plot not working

Tags: maxima

What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
atvalue(y(x),[x=0],1)$
desolve(diff(y(x),x)=y(x),y(x));
plot2d(y(x),[x,-6,6]);
```

Output:

```
plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range.
plot2d: nothing to plot
false
```

I want to plot y(x) which is obtained from a differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maxima `y(x) = ...` is an equation, and `y(x) := ...` is a function, and those two things are different. Try this:

```
atvalue (y(x), [x=0], 1)$
desolve (diff(y(x),x)=y(x), y(x));
define (y(x), rhs(%));
plot2d (y(x), [x, -6, 6]);
```

Here `define(y(x), ...)` is a different way to define a function. `define` evaluates the function body `rhs(%)` to yield `exp(x)` but `:=` quotes it (not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the result you see after the desolve does not mean y is defined as a function of x; in fact you obtain the same error if you change `y(x)` with `f(x)` (or any other unknown function) in plot2d. See the difference:

```
(%i9) atvalue(y(x),[x=0],1)$

(%i10) desolve(diff(y(x),x)=y(x),y(x));
                                           x
(%o10)                            y(x) = %e
(%i11) y(x);
(%o11)                               y(x)
(%i12) y(x):=%e^x;
                                            x
(%o12)                            y(x) := %e
(%i13) y(x);
                                        x
(%o13)                                %e
```

I don't know if there's a way to “transform” the equation (the result) into a function definition automatically. If I find a way, I will complete the answer.